# Send action to all components from controller

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember app I have a model, which is an array loaded from backend. Each item describes a widget. Each widget type is represented by Ember component. User puts input in each widget and now all the widgets needs to be evalueated at once (after pressing a button, which is located outside of all components).

How to achieve that? I thought I could use ember-component-inbound-actions and send an action to each component, however I don't know, how to bind arbitrary number of widgets to arbitrary number of controller properties (strings don't work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create `Ember.Service` which emits event, inject it into route or controller (place from where you send action when user clicks button) and all components. Then, you should subscribe in your components to event emitted from `Ember.Service`, or, if it is shared logic, you could create `Mixin` with specific method and use it in all components, and react to that action emitted from controller.

Example service:

```
export default Ember.Service.extend(Ember.Evented, {  
    emitButtonClicked() {
        this.trigger('buttonClicked');
    }
});
```

Example component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  theService: Ember.inject.service('theservice'),

  doSomethingWithInput() {
    this.set('randomProperty', true);
    console.log('Do something with input value: ' + this.get('inputVal'));
  },

  subscribeToService: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.get('theService').on('buttonClicked', this,  this.doSomethingWithInput);
  }),

  unsubscribeToService: Ember.on('willDestroyElement', function () {
    this.get('theService').off('buttonClicked', this, this.doSomethingWithInput);
  })

});
```

Example controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  theService: Ember.inject.service('theservice'),
  actions: {
    buttonClicked() {
        this.get('theService').emitButtonClicked();
    }
  }
});
```

And example template:

```
<button {{action 'buttonClicked'}}>Global Button</button>

First component:
{{my-component}}

Second component:
{{my-component}}
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/5f3a1cceeda23ecf5da1)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/5f3a1cceeda23ecf5da1)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. Is there an elegant way how to collect data from components? I know I could send an action from component to controller, however it seems to be a little hacky.

Comment: Sending actions from components to controller is a way to go. Ember 2.0 encourages you to use actions a lot - "data down actions up".

Comment: I have found out weird behavior - when I recreate the components (eg. via transiting to different route and back again), the non-existing components are still listening to the service (and I get "Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object"). How should th ecomponent properly "unsubscribe"?